# PHP Fsockopen check port 25

Tags: php, smtp

I have written a code to check port 25 of one of my local server . The smtp server is running on the server, but when i check with fsockopen, returns a connection refused error . So how i check whether SMTP is down or up using a simple php code .

Answer (score 0):

Are the php script and the smpt on the same machine? Have you checked the connection with telnet?

```
telnet your.local.server 25
```

Generally "Connection refused" means, what it says ;)

- smtp server is not running, or
- your server is not reachable (firewall?)

Comment: Hello, The script running on different machine . Ie from machine A i run the script and SMTP service running on server B .

Comment: I thought so. Have you checked the connection manually with telnet from the machine with the php script?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to write your server detail such as OS

check your firewall ,maybe it refuses your connection

And check connection with :

```
telnet your-server 25
```